# Mapping using objects in javascript - for in loop, how to do I map to specific HTML class and id?

Tags: javascript, object, mapping

I am trying to map a text from a javascript object to a specific h2 tag nested within many classes using a for in loop. How do I get the team object mapped into that h2 tag so it loops through?
Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="toprow">
     <div class="a-develop">
          <a>
            <ul class="info seatleft" id="firstcolumn">
                <li>
                    <h2>mike</h2>
                       ...
```

Javascript:

```
var names = {
    1: {

        team: "ben",

    },

    2: {

        team: "bar",

    }
};

function render() {

    for (var i in names) {
        var item = names[i],
            target = $("#firstcolumn" + i);

        target.find("h2").text(item.team);

    }

}

render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a typo. You have `<ul class="info seatleft" id="firstcolumn">` but then in your JavaScript you are calculating: `target = $("#firstcolumn" + i);` where i will be 1 or 2 in this case but you don't have an element with `id="firstcolumn1"` or `id="firstcolumn2"` so basically your target will be invalid.

Comment: ah right, thank you. Is there a way to name and map objects without using a number?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by map here? As far as the objects 1 and 2, you can give them any names and still use for .. in. Take a look at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for  an in depth explanation.

Comment: meaning map the objects to the html <h2> DOM element... and thank you, for the link.